# Is there a way to stylize responses from AWS Lex

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lex

I'm using Lambda and Lex to return responses to end users, however I'm wondering if there is a way to bold or italicize certain words in a response.  I know it would be parsed by the platform running Lex which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it depends on your output channel.

For example if you are using **Facebook Messenger**, then try:

**BOLD** = surround with asterisks * ... *
*ITALICS* = surround with underscores _ ... _
<strike>Strikethrough</strike> = surround with dashes - ... -

(just tested and works in desktop messenger, but didn't work in mobile messenger app)

So check the output channel requirements for style options, and then just be careful with how it is passed as correct JSON and parsed through Lex.